# finding inverse of function in ordered pair notation

Tags: real-analysis, functions

$$f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} $$
where f is defined as $$f(x,y) =(\text{somethingforx},\text{somethingfory}) $$
I dont want to post the exact question because I would like to get it on my own, but I am having trouble finding the best way to find the inverse of a function when it is given in ordered pair notation such as here. Any methods on how to proceed would be very helpful. 
Thanks

Comment: I think you mean $f = \{(x,y)\}$, not $f(x,y) = \cdots$.

Comment: hey ethan, let me give an example: $f(x,y)=(5x-3y,7y-2x)$ (this example is made up so im not sure if it is bijective or not but, this is notation i am given.

Comment: You do it exactly the same.  $f(x,y)$ is injective if $(5x-3y, 7y-2x)=(5a-3y,7b-2a) \implies (x,y) = (a,b)$.  And $f$ is surective if there any $(w,u)$ you can find an $(x,y) $ where $(5x+3y, 7y-2x)= (w, y)$.

Comment: i understand how to show if fxn is bijective, however showing the formula for the inverse is correct is confusing me. if $f^{-1}(y,x)$ is the inverse of $f(x,y)$ then for some $a,b$ $f(a,b)=f^{-1}(b,a)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example $f(x,y)=(5x-3y,7y-2x)$

you do it exactly the same way.

$f(w,u) = (5w - 3u, 7u-2w) = (x,y)$

Now solve for $(w,u)$ in terms of $(x,y)$.

$x = 5w -3u; y = 7u-2w$

$w = \frac {x+3u}5 = \frac {7u-y}2$

$2(x+3u) = 5(7u-y)$

$2x+5y = 29u$

$u = \frac {2x+5y}{29}$

And so $w =\frac {x+3 \frac {2x+5y}{29}}5 = \frac {7  \frac {2x+5y}{29} -y}2 =$

$\frac {35x + 15y}{145} = \frac {14x+6y}{58}=\frac {7x+3y}{29}$.

So $f^{-1}(x,y) = (w,u) = (\frac {7x+3y}{29},\frac {2x+5y}{29})$

But finding an inverse isn't the best way to prove something is invertible

It is better to show if $f(x,y) = f(w,u)$ whether that must mean $(x, y) = (w,u)$ or not.

So if $(5x-3y, 7y-2x) = (5w-3u, 7u-2w)$ then

$5x - 3y = 5w - 3u$ so $5x - 5w = 3y-3u$ so $(x-w) = \frac 35(y-u)$

And $7y-2x = 7u-2w$ so $7y-7u = 2x-2w$ so $x-w = \frac 72(y-u)$.

So $\frac 35(y-u) = \frac 72(y-u)$ but that is only possible if $y-u=0$

So $y=u$ and so $x-w = 0$ and $x = w$.  So $(x,y) = (w,u)$ and $f$ is one to one.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse relation of f is

{ ( ( something for x, something for y), (x,y) ) | ((x,y) , (somethingforx, somethingfory) ) belong to f}.

In general the inverse of R is

{ (b,a) | (a,b) belong to R}

Here

a = (x,y)

and

b = ( something for x, something for y)